# How to insert a document in MongoDB stitch with rule enabled on a field

Tags: android, mongodb, mbaas

I am trying the new MongoDb stitch but cannot work out with defining rules on fields.

When I try to insert a document it collection with no rules on any Fields or only in Top level document it inserts fine.
But as soon as I add a Field an write a rule it gives error "document cannot be written to". Even when the rule is "{}" which always evaluates to true.
Below is a sample insert Pipeline and defined rule.

**TOP LEVEL DOCUMENT: 
R {} W "blank" 
FIELDS :
name W {}**

Insert Pipeline
Stage 1 :

```
Service: "built-in", Action "literal", 
args:"{
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "Don Giovanni",
      "cuisine": "Italian",
      "location": "Chicago, IL",
      "comments": [
        {
          "user_id": "leporello",
          "comment": "Molto bene"
        },
        {
          "user_id": "59b256814fdd1f75d5e1dce3",
          "comment": "insertion"
        },
        {
          "user_id": "59b256814fdd1f75d5e1dce3",
          "comment": "good food"
        },
        {
          "user_id": "59b256814fdd1f75d5e1dce3",
          "comment": "very good food"
        },
        {
          "user_id": "59b256814fdd1f75d5e1dce3",
          "comment": "insertion"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}"

Stage 2 :
Service :"mongodb-atlas", Action:"insert",database:"guidebook", collection:"restaurants"
```

Answer (score 1):

If your write rule at the top-level document is blank, Stitch will try to find a writeable rule for each of the fields/arrays/sub-documents that would apply to the document you're trying to insert.

In your case, it's not enough to have a *write all* (i.e. `{}`) rule for the `name` field, you need one for each other field present in your document (i.e. `_id`, `location`, `cuisine` and `comments`), as shown in the picture below. Note that you must declare the `comments` field as `Array` not `Any` for your insert to work.

You can find out more about the Stitch rules interaction in the Stitch documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/rules/mongodb-rules/#mongodb-service-rules-interaction

[image: Stitch rules]

Comment: My problem was I hadn't written write for "all other fields" and left it blank.As soon as I wrote a rule for it, It works fine.